# how to change class name of an element by jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="bestAnswerControl">
    <div id="ct100_contentplaceholder_lvanswer_control_divbestanswer"  
         class="IsBestAnswer"></div>
</div>
```

I want to add:

```
.bestanswer
{
    // some attribute
}
```

I want to replace `class="IsBestAnswer"` of div to `class="bestanswer"` by jquery. 
How do I do this?

I am using this approach:

```
$('.IsBestAnswer').addclass('bestanswer');
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Define "is not working". `addClass` should work fine

Answer (score 148, accepted):

```
$('.IsBestAnswer').addClass('bestanswer').removeClass('IsBestAnswer');
```

Case in method names is important, so no `addclass`.

[jQuery `addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass)
[jQuery `removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass)

Comment: If you call it with no parameters it will remove all classes from the element: e.g. $('#IsBestAnswer').removeClass().addClass('bestanswer').

Comment: late 2012 the `Element.classList` introduced by browsers, that returns a `DOMTokenList` that have methods to manipulation of class attribute of a html element.

Answer (score 50):

Instead of removeClass and addClass, you can also do it like this:

```
$('.IsBestAnswer').toggleClass('IsBestAnswer bestanswer');
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$('.IsBestAnswer').removeClass('IsBestAnswer').addClass('bestanswer');
```

Your code has two problems:

1. The selector `.IsBestAnswe` does not match what you thought
2. It's `addClass()`, not `addclass()`.

Also, I'm not sure whether you want to *replace* the class or *add* it. The above will replace, but remove the `.removeClass('IsBestAnswer')` part to add only:

```
$('.IsBestAnswer').addClass('bestanswer');
```

You should decide whether to use camelCase or all-lowercase in your CSS classes too (e.g. `bestAnswer` vs. `bestanswer`).