# How to add class to div depending on url in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I add a class to a specific class on a specific page using pure Javascript? I've played around with a number of different code-snippets but can't manage to get anything to work. I'm looking for something like the following:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href == 'http://specific-page.com') {
      $(somecode).find('existingClass').addClass('newClass');
   };
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you replace somecode with the element type i.e. div, input, ul, li?

Comment: Did you try using find('.existingClass'). You need to specify selector. I suppose 'existingClass' is a class, so you need '.' in front of it

Answer (score 3):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) plus [NodeList.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Moreover, you can take a look to the [Element.classList methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

The snippet:

```js
//
// For test purposes only
//
window.location.href1 = 'http://specific-page.com';


if (window.location.href1 == 'http://specific-page.com') {
  document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv .existingClass').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    ele.classList.add('newClass');
  });
};
```

```css
.existingClass {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.newClass {
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <p class="existingClass">Thbis is a sample string</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
<script>
  if (window.location.href == 'http://specific-page.com') {
    $('.existingClass').addClass('newClass');
  };
</script>
```

What you have to do is to use the class you are looking for as a selector, in this case it is `".existingClass"`.

There are many other ways to do it depending on what you are trying to acchive.

Other post:

[jquery change class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)

[jQuery changing css class to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835440/jquery-changing-css-class-to-div)

[how to change class name of an element by jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959236/how-to-change-class-name-of-an-element-by-jquery)

Comment: The OP says "pure javascript".  I'm assuming he doesn't want a jQuery solution.

Comment: He has posted as an example a jQuery code. I assumed OP was referencing jQuery as JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest but get elements by classname will fail on some browsers like older i.e.

compatibility can be found here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Browser_compatibility

```
 // JavaScript Document

window.onload = init;
var divsWithClass = null;


function init() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("some value you care about") >= 0) {
        this.divsWithClass = document.getElementsByClassName("Some Class Name");
        var index = 0;
        while (index < divsWithClass.length) {
            divsWithClass[index].className += " newClass";
            index++;
        }
    }
    console.log(divsWithClass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setAttribute` to set the **Attribute** *class* to a new value. In the value, you can add the new class to the existing class value. Also, the `getElementsByClassName` returns the Elements list, so you need to select the right element Appropriately. I am using the element at first index below.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("existingClass");
elements[0].setAttribute( "class", "existingClass" + " newClass" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Vannila JS, then you can use the code from below. It doesn't use jQuery.

```js
if ( window.location.href == 'http://specific-page.com' ) {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("currentClass")[0];
  var newClass = el.getAttribute("class");
  newClass += " myNewClass"; 
  el.setAttribute("class", newClass)
  console.log(el)
  }
```